# How to Move Button from Right to Left in Xamarin(iOS)

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin, uibutton

I am New to Xamarin and iOS. I am making App in Visual Studio with Xamarin. I want to move my Button from Right Side to left Side. for that I have use below code :

```
fabButton.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Plus Math-24"), UIControlState.Normal);

            pt = fabButton.Center;

            UIView.Animate(2, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
                () => { 

                    fabButton.Center = new CGPoint(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Left - fabButton.Frame.Width / 15, fabButton.Center.Y);},
            () => {
                fabButton.Center = pt;}
            );
```

My button is moving but it get back to my Previous Position. Any Help be Appreciated.

This is my Image :

[image]

**UpDate :**

When I try different code it work better

**Change Code :**

```
 UIView.Animate(2, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
               () =>
               {

                   fabButton.Center = new CGPoint(50,611);
               },
           () =>
           {

           }
           );
```

Normal Screen :

[image]

when Click on button :

[image]

But it have some issue The Button is go some height upper side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh It was silly mistake why it goes upper side :

I change the code to this way.

Instead of my point

```
CGPoint(50,611);
```

to

`CGPoint(50, fabButton.Center.Y);`

because i want move my button to X direction then why I want to change the Y direction value.

```
UIView.Animate(2, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
               () =>
               {

                   fabButton.Center = new CGPoint(50,fabButton.Center.Y);
               },
           () =>
           {

           }
           );
```

**Normal Screen :**

[image]

After Button Click :

[image]